# How to determine the exact solution of a differential equation using variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \mathbf x'=\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 1 \\
1 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf x +
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4t \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf x_1= e^{-2t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
\mathbf x_2=e^{-4t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
$$
I know that $\mathbf x_p(t)=\mathbf X(t)\int\mathbf X^{-1}\mathbf g(t)dt\\$
$$\mathbf X=[\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2]$$
By applying this formula I produced the following.
$$
\mathbf X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf X^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2\\
1/2 & -1/2\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}\int \begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2\\
1/2 & -1/2\\
\end{pmatrix}
*
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4t \\
\end{pmatrix}dt=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
(t/2+t^2)+(t/2+t^2) \\
(t/2-t^2)+(-t/2+t^2) \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
t+2t^2 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This answer is not correct, but I do not know where I am going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

$$ \mathbf x'=\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 1 \\
1 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf x +
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4t \\
\end{pmatrix}\\$$

We have the homogeneous components:

$$\mathbf x_1(t) = e^{-2t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} , \mathbf x_2(t) = e^{-4t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives us:

$$\mathbf X(t) =[\mathbf x_1(t), \mathbf x_2(t)] = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{-2 t} & e^{-4 t} \\
 e^{-2 t} & -e^{-4 t} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$
\mathbf X^{-1}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{e^{2 t}}{2} & \frac{e^{2 t}}{2} \\
 \frac{e^{4 t}}{2} & -\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\displaystyle \mathbf X_p(t)=\mathbf X(t)\int\mathbf X^{-1}(t)\mathbf g(t)dt = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{-2 t} & e^{-4 t} \\
 e^{-2 t} & -e^{-4 t} \\
\end{pmatrix} \int \left(\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{e^{2 t}}{2} & \frac{e^{2 t}}{2} \\
 \frac{e^{4 t}}{2} & -\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4t \\
\end{pmatrix}\right)dt$$

$$\mathbf X_p(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{-2 t} & e^{-4 t} \\
 e^{-2 t} & -e^{-4 t} \\
\end{pmatrix} .\displaystyle \int
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 e^{2 t} t+\frac{e^{2 t}}{2} \\
 \frac{e^{4 t}}{2}-2 e^{4 t} t \\
\end{pmatrix}dt = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^{-2 t} & e^{-4 t} \\
 e^{-2 t} & -e^{-4 t} \\
\end{pmatrix} . 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} e^{2 t} \left(2 t-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{2} e^{4 t} \left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence:

$$\mathbf X_p(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{t}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} (3 t-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Recall:

$$\mathbf X(t) = \mathbf X_h(t) + \mathbf X_p(t) = c_1\mathbf e^{-2t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{-4t}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{t}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} (3 t-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$